# Census Data Mapper - what tool they used to do it?

Tags: web-mapping, web-service, census

The Census Data Mapper is a web mapping application of the Census Bureau used to create instant web maps out of the Census data which are stored in the Census databases.

I was wondering what tools are they using to make that service? For example, what mapping server, what client, and so on.

Here is the link to the Data Mapper: http://datamapper.geo.census.gov/map.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This map has been made with Flash (kill it with fire), so it won't work on mobile and many non-Windows devices. It's also very clunky.

You could easily make something that's much more modern and works on all devices with [MangoMap](https://mangomap.com) without writing any code.

If you want to code something and host it yourself then a Linux/PostGIS/GeoServer/Leaflet stack or GeoNode would be the path of least resistance.

I'm the CEO of MangoMap, if you have any questions you can contact me at [chris@mangomap.com](https://mangomap.com).